# 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router' error

Tags: reactjs

Such error occurred in my project while building

```sh
WARNING in ./node_modules/react-router-config/esm/react-router-config.js 41:38-44
export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router'
```

Along with this runtime error

```sh
react_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Router.computeRootMatch is not a function
```

package.json

```
 "react-router-config": "^5.1.1",
 "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
 "react": "17.0.1",
 "react-dom": "17.0.1",
```

I have not installed any new packages and cannot figure out solution

Answer (score 1):

You certainly have installed React Router v6. `Switch` is only available in V5 and below. You need to use `Routes` now.

Comment: I did not add any new packages or upgraded existed

Comment: Please show your import, it's impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: This error occures in react-router-config lib, not my code

Comment: Why do you need react-router-config? React-router-dom has everything you need. Again, without seeing your import, we can't help you.